# Computer starts operating slow after crashing due to power outage. I need help debugging

Tags: 20.04, performance, crash, amd-processor

**Summary:**

After an unscheduled restart my computer **becomes an order of magnitude slower**. If manually restarted afterwards, the computer reverts back to its expected performance.

**Detailed description:**

While the computer is running normally, this is the score it gets while running a standard *geekbench* score: https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/13619045

If the computer crashes, or loses power due to an electricity outage, and has to be booted normally back again it becomes super slow. If I run *geeksbench* again this happens: https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/13618924 (**an order of magnitude slower**)

I have no ideia how to debug this problem. Can somebody suggest a plan of action to debug the situation?

Things I have tried:

- updating bios,
- switching processor
- trying a different graphics card
- using only on RAM stick

Specs:

- X399 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B09)
- AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2970WX 24-Core Processor
- 32Gb Kingston DDR4 2400mhz (2x16Gb)
- NIVIDA 1080 gtx

**EDIT:**

Thanks to someone's answer I was able to extract logs regarding a good boot and a bad boot. Unfortunately I'm not able to find anything weird myself. Here they are:

Bad boot: https://privatebin.net/?b17e26b3c0f22e17#2BAJAZPkriuv1w2qZ1YXq1QkwkhCjpTafjjdHs8TcEko

Good boot: https://privatebin.net/?26f18a19ce07b211#37gdQV998RX8tvtUyqHp9RmcpuC92gypZvc5mPQ3gzmY

I removed timestamps to be able to compare them using: `colordiff -y -W 256 broken.txt working.txt`

Comment: How often is power abruptly severed from the machine? If it’s more than “once in a blue moon” you may want to look at getting a decent UPS to protect your investment 

Comment: Unfortunately it is a blue-moon every week here. Do you suggest any good UPS for a system like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the startup logs of the two types of reboots. Use `sudo journalctl --list-boots | tee boots.txt` (very slow the first time you run it - journalctl has to index all the logs) to get the index number and `sudo journalctl -b #` will let you pick a boot from the list (# values are `0`:current boot, `-1`:previous boot, `-2`:the one before that,...).

There will be a difference!

Comment: Thanks for teaching me this. I wondered for quite sometime on how to do it and was not having luck searching it out on google. Unfortunately I'm not able to find anything weird on the logs. I have taken out the timestamps to facilitate diffs. This is the poor performance bootup log https://privatebin.net/?b17e26b3c0f22e17#2BAJAZPkriuv1w2qZ1YXq1QkwkhCjpTafjjdHs8TcEko and this is the well working boot https://privatebin.net/?26f18a19ce07b211#37gdQV998RX8tvtUyqHp9RmcpuC92gypZvc5mPQ3gzmY . Can you lend me your expertise? `colordiff -y -W 256 broken.txt working.txt`